# What is the correct way to use extends on a static method that uses generics?

Tags: java, generics, static-methods, extends

I am attempting to make a static method that uses generics.

I would like the method to only take parameters of types that implement comparable.

I have attempted to do this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> ArrayList<T extends Comparable<T>> foo(ArrayList<T extends Comparable<T>> bar)
```

but it results in a syntax error.

Comment: you can't `extend` static methods, they can't be over-ridden

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Thanks, that removed some errors. Is there still a way that I can enforce parameters so that I know I'm getting a comparable object?

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't have to rebind your generic parameter.  This works fine without the bounds in the `ArrayList` or in the argument:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> ArrayList<T> foo(ArrayList<T> bar)
```

The main reason this works:  `T` is already defined to be in the bound of a `Comparable`.